# How to prove that an equation can be divided by any n?

Tags: list-manipulation, logic, proof

I'm new to Mathematica and came across with the problem. I can't prove that (for example) `2*n` is always even no matter what `n` is.  I could do this If I had some range. (Would use `Table`, `Mod` and `Length` function) But I don't know what to use in this situation. And one more question please. Is it possible to have a list (1,3,5,7) and get the indexes of prime numbers (3,4) and both numbers and indexes together (`{3,5}`, `{4, 7}`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3 is also a prime number.

Comment: For the first, `Simplify[Mod[2*n + 2, 2], n \[Element] Integers]` evaluates to 0, which means that `2*n + 2` is even. Alternatively, `EvenQ[2 # + 2] & /@ Range[-20, 20, 2]` yields a list of `True`'s, and you can extend the list to any maximum or minimum integer you want.

Answer (score 3):

For the first, here are two options (the second from [BlacKow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8114/blackow)):

```
Simplify[Mod[2*n + 2, 2], n ∈ Integers]
Simplify[Divisible[2*n + 2, 2], n \[Element] Integers]
(* 0 *)
(* True *)
```

means that `2*n + 2` is always even. Alternatively, checking a "few" cases:

```
EvenQ[2 # + 2] & /@ Range[-200, 200, 2] // And @@ # &
(* True *)
```

---

For the second question (and for future reference: asking two questions in one post that are not closely related is considered against the rules):

Sample list:

```
list = Range[1, 20, 2]
{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}
```

Selecting:

```
Select[Transpose[{Range[Length@list], list}], PrimeQ[#[[2]]] &]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}, {6, 11}, {7, 13}, {9, 17}, {10, 19}} *)
```

Comment: or you can use `Divisible` instead of `Mod`

Comment: @BlacKow. Oh yeah, that's better!

Comment: is `2n` not a more complete and simpler test that `2n+2`?

Comment: `FullSimplify[Mod[2 n, 2] == 0, n \[Element] Integers]` returns `True`

Answer (score 1):

Another method for the second question uses the `Position` function along with the `_?` (`PatternTest`) construct:

```
list = Range[1, 20, 2]
Transpose[{Flatten[Position[list, _?PrimeQ]], Select[list, PrimeQ]}]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 7}, {6, 11}, {7, 13}, {9, 17}, {10, 19}} *)
```

Comment: Aren't you testing for being prime twice? What about `Transpose@{#, list[[#]]} &@Flatten[Position[list, _?PrimeQ]]`